# how use mysql SEC_TO_TIME function with jooq

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

MYSQL:

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,now(),'2019-02-16 16:00:00')) from dual
```

Jooq has been used recently,but I don't know how to use SEC_TO_TIME with jooq

please help me

```
DSL.timestampDiff(orderSellGroupMain.VALIDTIME,DSL.now())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always when you are encountering missing vendor-specific functionality in jOOQ, your best guess is to use "plain SQL templating":
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating

So, just write a function like this:

```java
class MyDSL {
    static Field<Time> secToTime(Field<? extends Number> field) {
        return DSL.field("sec_to_time({0})", SQLDataType.TIME, field);
    }
}
```